# is HttpContext async safe in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

Based on what i have read `asp.net core` have dropped the synchronization context. This means that the thread that executes codes after `await` call might not be the same one that executes codes before `await`

So is `HttpContext` still safe to use in `async` methods? or is it possible to get a different context after the `await` call?

For example in a controller action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var context1 = HttpContext;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    var context2 = HttpContext;
    ....
}
```

could context1 be different from context2?

and the recommended way to get the context in none controller method is by dependency injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`

Is `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` safe from `async` `await` pattern?

I.E. could context1 be different from context2?

```
public async void Foo(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    var context1 = accessor.HttpContext;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    var context2 = accessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Comment: If you are in controller where you have direct access to `HttpContext` use this. If you are in a service or somewhere else where you don't have direct HttpContext use IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext which was designed to be async-safe.

Comment: @ckuri is there any documentation for that? Can't seem to get the logic of how asp.net core is able to restore reference to HttpContext without SynchronizationContext

Comment: [Internally](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs) the accessor uses [AsyncLocal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1) which preserves information along an async call graph. The example there shows a console application which has no SynchronisationContext. The [ASP .NET Core documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context) only mentions this implicitly at the end when they say the accessor doesn't work when you don't await your async calls.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So is HttpContext still safe to use in async methods? or is it possible to get a different context after the await call?

The whole problem with `async` and `HttpContext` and ASP.NET pre-Core was due to the fact that code usually got its `HttpContext` from `HttpContext.Current`. ASP.NET is a multithreaded server, and each `await` could resume on a different thread. So ASP.NET pre-Core had to have an `AspNetSynchronizationContext` that managed setting `HttpContext.Current` before the asynchronous code resumed.

The modern ASP.NET Core *does not have* a synchronization context. But that's fine, because it *also* doesn't have `HttpContext.Current`. The only way of getting the `HttpContext` instance is through a local property (e.g., `HttpContext` on your controller class) or dependency injection (`IHttpContextAccessor`).

(Pedantic note: the explanation above is a bit simplified - the ASP.NET pre-Core synchronization context did handle other things besides `HttpContext.Current` - but the same overall exaplanation holds for all of its other responsibilities - i.e., they are not necessary in the Core world)

So, it is not possible for the context to be different. They are the same property - the same object instance. The problem with ASP.NET pre-Core was a *static* property value `HttpContext.Current`, which has been removed in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: you are my hero for async related questions

Comment: @Steve out of curiosity, im wondering if you could add some remarks on AsyncLocal<T> and why that would not be suitable to implement a static HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core (assuming HttpContext.Current were read-only) - because at a glance it appears to still be technically feasible, even with multi-threading; perhaps there is also the "opinionated design" factor to take into consideration?

Comment: @nicholas: `AsyncLocal<T>` can be used to implement a static `HttpContext.Current`. I believe the primary reason it wasn't done is because of opinionated design. Quasi-globals and implicit state are generally not considered a good design, although there are exceptions to that general rule. By injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`, a component is explicitly stating its dependence on that implicit state.

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#do-not-access-httpcontext-from-multiple-threads

> HttpContext is NOT thread-safe. Accessing HttpContext from multiple
> threads in parallel can result in undefined behavior such as hangs,
> crashes, and data corruption.
>
> Do not do this: The following example makes three parallel requests
> and logs the incoming request path before and after the outgoing HTTP
> request. The request path is accessed from multiple threads,
> potentially in parallel.

```
public class AsyncBadSearchController : Controller
{       
    [HttpGet("/search")]
    public async Task<SearchResults> Get(string query)
    {
       var query1 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.Google, query);
       var query2 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.Bing, query);
       var query3 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.DuckDuckGo, query);

       await Task.WhenAll(query1, query2, query3);

       var results1 = await query1;
       var results2 = await query2;
       var results3 = await query3;

       return SearchResults.Combine(results1, results2, results3);
    }       

    private async Task<SearchResults> SearchAsync(SearchEngine engine, string query)
    {
        var searchResults = _searchService.Empty();
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting search query from {path}.", 
                                    HttpContext.Request.Path);
            searchResults = _searchService.Search(engine, query);
            _logger.LogInformation("Finishing search query from {path}.", 
                                    HttpContext.Request.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed query from {path}", 
                             HttpContext.Request.Path);
        }

        return await searchResults;
    }
}
```

> Do this: The following example copies all data from the incoming
> request before making the three parallel requests.

```
public class AsyncGoodSearchController : Controller
{       
    [HttpGet("/search")]
    public async Task<SearchResults> Get(string query)
    {
        string path = HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var query1 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.Google, query,
                             path);
        var query2 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.Bing, query, path);
        var query3 = SearchAsync(SearchEngine.DuckDuckGo, query, path);

        await Task.WhenAll(query1, query2, query3);

        var results1 = await query1;
        var results2 = await query2;
        var results3 = await query3;

        return SearchResults.Combine(results1, results2, results3);
    }

       private async Task<SearchResults> SearchAsync(SearchEngine engine, string query,
                                                  string path)
       {
        var searchResults = _searchService.Empty();
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting search query from {path}.",
                                   path);
            searchResults = await _searchService.SearchAsync(engine, query);
            _logger.LogInformation("Finishing search query from {path}.", path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed query from {path}", path);
        }

        return await searchResults;
    }
}
```